# C: uint16_t subtraction behavior in gcc

Tags: c, gcc, unsigned, stdint

I'm trying to subtract two unsigned ints and compare the result to a signed int (or a literal).  When using `unsigned int` types the behavior is as expected.  When using `uint16_t` (from `stdint.h`) types the behavior is not what I would expect.  The comparison was done using gcc 4.5.
Given the following code:

```
unsigned int a;
unsigned int b;

a = 5;
b = 20;

printf("%u\n", (a-b) < 10);
```

The output is 0, which is what I expected.  Both a and b are unsigned, and b is larger than a, so the result is a large unsigned number which is greater than 10.  Now if I change a and b to type uint16_t:

```
uint16_t a;
uint16_t b;

a = 5;
b = 20;

printf("%u\n", (a-b) < 10);
```

The output is 1.  Why is this?  Is the result of subtraction between two uint16_t types stored in an int in gcc?  If I change the `10` to `10U` the output is again 0, which seems to support this (if the subtraction result is stored as an int and the comparison is made against an unsigned int than the subtraction results will be converted to an unsigned int).

Comment: The result is not just "stored in an int'. The entire subtraction is performed as `int` subtraction, i.e. both `uint16_t` operands are converted to `int` before the subtraction even has a chance to begin. Read about integral promotions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because calculations are not done with types below int / unsigned int (char, short, unsigned short etc; but not long, unsigned long etc), but they are first promoted to one of int or unsigned int. "uint16_t" is possibly "unsigned short" on your implementation, which is promoted to "int" on your implementation. So the result of that calculation then is "-15", which is smaller than 10.

On older implementations that calculate with 16bit, "int" may not be able to represent all values of "unsigned short" because both have the same bitwidth. Such implementations must promote "unsigned short" to "unsigned int". On such implementations, your comparison results in "0".

Answer (score 5):

Before both the `-` and `<` operations are performed, a set of conversions called the *usual arithmetic conversions* are applied to convert the operands to a common type.  As part of this process, the *integer promotions* are applied, which promote types narrower than `int` or `unsigned int` to one of those two types.

In the first case, the types of `a` and `b` are `unsigned int`, so no change of types occurs due to the `-` operator - the result is an `unsigned int` with the large positive value `UINT_MAX - 14`.  Then, because `int` and `unsigned int` have the same rank, the value `10` with type `int` is converted to `unsigned int`, and the comparison is then performed resulting in the value `0`.

In the second case, it is apparent that on your implementation the type `int` can hold all the values of the type `uint16_t`.  This means that when the integer promotions are applied, the values of `a` and `b` are promoted to type `int`.  The subtraction is performed, resulting in the value `-15` with type `int`.  Both operands to the `<` are already `int`, so no conversions are performed; the result of the `<` is `1`.

When you use a `10U` in the latter case, the result of `a - b` is still `-15` with type `int`.  Now, however, the usual arithmetic conversions cause this value to be converted to `unsigned int` (just as the `10` was in the first example), which results in the value `UINT_MAX - 14`; the result of the `<` is `0`.

Comment: "*it is apparent that on your implementation the type int can hold all the values of the type uint16_t*" that's the key, nevertheless I'm surprised that *gcc* (Linux) does that `unsigned short` to `int` promotion (and not to `unsigned`) before performing the comparison (which in my case was not the expected result)... The GNU folks have surely a good reason for this choice, but I think that can be misleading to have all values *unsigned* and then do the comparison with a *negative* operand... Maybe the promotion should only be done up to the largest type (16 bits here).

Comment: @e2-e4: These promotion rules are part of the C standard, not something the compiler authors decided on.  The rule of thumb to remember is that arithmetic is never done in types narrower than `int` / `unsigned int`, so if you are dealing with narrower unsigned types and want to control the type in which the arithmetic is done, convert an operand to `unsigned int` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. (6.3.1.8)

Answer (score 0):

When `uin16_t` is a sub-range of `int`, `(a-b) < 10` is performed using `int` math.

Use an `unsigned` constant to gently nudge the left side to `unsigned` math.

```
// printf("%u\n", (a-b) < 10);
printf("%d\n", (0u + a - b) < 10);  // Using %d as the result of a compare is int.
// or to quiet some picky warnings
printf("%d\n", (0u + a - b) < 10u);
```

`(a - b) < 10u` also works with this simple code, yet the idea I am suggesting to to perform both sides as `unsigned` math as that may be needed with more complex code.