# Is subtraction and comparison with unsigned integers in C / C++ well defined?

Tags: c++, c, undefined-behavior

As an expansion to the question ["Is unsigned integer subtraction defined behavior?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221409/is-unsigned-integer-subtraction-defined-behavior), I am confused about the following behavior.

In the code below, note that `A = 50` and `B = 100` are stored as unsigned 16-bit integers and the subtraction `A - B = -50 = 65486 (mod 2^16 - 1)`. If I store the result of the subtraction in `D` (an unsigned 16-bit integer) and then evaluate `D > 4000` I get `true` since `65486 > 4000.` That makes sense.

If I forgo storing `A - B` and evaluate `A - B > 4000` directly I get false. This seem inconsistent. Is this the expected result? Why? Is this always the correct behavior or am I in the land of "undefined behavior".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
  uint16_t A = 50;
  uint16_t B = 100;

  uint16_t D = A - B;     // D = 65486                                                                                        
  printf("D = %u\n", D);

  int R = D > 4000;       // R = 1 (true)                                                                                 
  printf("R = %d\n", R);

  int S = A - B > 4000;   // S = 0 (false)                                                                                
  printf("S = %d\n", S);

  return 0;
}
```

BTW, this behavior seems to contradict the behavior in the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047956/c-uint16-t-subtraction-behavior-in-gcc), which further confuses me. If I change `uint16_t` to `uint32_t` above than I get

```
D = 4294967246
R = 1
S = 1
```

which seems correct to me.

Update: It seems the best detailed answer is that `uint16_t` gets promoted to a `int` (`int` is 32-bit on my system) and so `A - B > 4000` is done with *signed* arithmetic. Whereas when I switch to `uint32_t` no promotion is performed (already 32-bits wide) and so `A - B > 4000` is done with *unsigned* arithmetic. This would explain it.

P.S. I know folks want to be first to answer, but just saying "integer promotion" is not a useful answer.

Comment: Integer promotions.

Comment: Which integer promotions? If A and B are promoted to 32-unsigned ints then A - B > 4000 should be true. If they are promoted to signed ints that makes even less sense. Specifically what promotions are occurring?

Comment: See [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8) and [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1).

Comment: (And yeah, they make unfortunately little sense.)

Comment: Are you saying that A and B promoted to signed ints? -- that doesn't explain the behavior when I switch to unit32_t.

Comment: It depends: is `int` 32  or 16 bit on your system?  You will get different answers.

Comment: sigh .. I don't think folks are actually reading the question ... integer promotion may be the answer but *which* promotions? And why isn't the same promotion happening for 32-bit number (or non-promotion).

Comment: " If A and B are promoted to 32-unsigned ints" --> wrong hypothesis.  Try " If A and B are promoted to 32-signed ints"

Comment: What is `INT_MAX` on your system?

Comment: @chux -- so you are saying uint16_t is promoted to int and uint32_t is not promoted at all? That would explain the result. (sizeof(int) = 4 so I am using 32-bit ints.)

Comment: If `int/unsigned` == 16, `uint32_t` is not promoted - remains `uint32_t`.  If `int/unsigned` == 32, `uint32_t` is promoted promoted to `unsigned`.  If `int/unsigned` == 64, `uint32_t` is promoted to `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I forgo storing A - B and evaluate A - B > 4000 directly I get false. This seem inconsistent.

Yes it does from a cursory look.

However, when the expression `A-B` is evaluated, both are promoted to `int` before the subtraction is performed. Hence, `A - B > 5000` evaluates to false.

You can read up on "Usual Arithmetic Conversions" at http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion.

Re. *But what about when I switch to `unit32_t`*:

When both operands are of type `unit32_t`, the result is also of type `unit32_t` on a platform where `sizeof(int)` is 4, not `int`.

Comment: But what about when I switch to `unit32_t`? I should get false then too!